System.Xml.XmlException: 'The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.'
Wrote the code converter csv file to xml file and when i started it i have an error:
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var csvFile = @"sbor.csv";
        var xmlFile = @"sbor.xml";

        var xml = ConvertCSVToXml(csvFile);
        File.WriteAllText(xmlFile, xml.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("CSV converted to XML successfully.");
     }

     private static XElement ConvertCSVToXml(string csvFile)
     {
          XElement root = new XElement("xml"); 
          var nodeName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(csvFile); 

          var lines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);

          var headers = lines[0].Split(',').Select(header => header.Trim()).ToArray(); 

          var dataLines = lines.Skip(1);
          dataLines.ToList().ForEach(line =>
          {
               var node = new XElement(nodeName);
               var data = line.Split(',').Select(field => 
                  field.Trim()).ToList();
        
               for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
               {
                    node.Add(new XElement(headers[i], data[i]));
               }
               root.Add(node);
          });

          return root;
}

}
The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name. I tried a lot and can't understand the problem.

As is said in error message. An XName does not allow its value to contain a space (' ') character. You may have used Trim to remove the space from beginning and ending, but you forget to remove the space inside the content. Try header => header.Trim().Replace(" ", "-")

@ZelgiusLiu anyway, the same error comes out

Print your header to console of put a breakpoint in the debugger and look at the string that is being written.

@ShiryazdanUshurbakiev Does the same error mean after you replace all space characters and it still throws error that your name for xml node contains space?

@ZelgiusLiu yes, there were err in '  var node = new XElement(nodeName); '

@ShiryazdanUshurbakiev Then I suggest you add breakpoint here and see what the value exactly is when it throws the error.

would be nice to add a csv example so we can reproduce an error

i have strong believe , that @ZelgiusLiu meant same.
your problem that XML dont like space INSIDE column name
if you run your code (since you did not provide example i have to make my own)
this is my csv file:
col 1, col2, col3,col 4, col5
r1,r2,r3,r4, r5
v1,v2,v3,4,5

when i run your code as is i got same error:
XmlException: The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.

then i changed the way , you are loading headers (replace/remove space)
var headers = lines[0].Split(',').Select(header => header.Trim().Replace(" ", string.Empty)).ToArray();


and i gor result :
<xml>
  <sbor>
    <col1>r1</col1>
    <col2>r2</col2>
    <col3>r3</col3>
    <col4>r4</col4>
    <col5>r5</col5>
  </sbor>
  <sbor>
    <col1>v1</col1>
    <col2>v2</col2>
    <col3>v3</col3>
    <col4>4</col4>
    <col5>5</col5>
  </sbor>
</xml>

